# Significance test for the mean squared error skill score (MSESS)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mse

I am looking for a test statistic whether a calculated value of the mean squared error skill score is significantly different from zero. The MSESS is defined as:

$MSESS=1− \frac{MSE_H}{MSE_O}$

Where $MSE_H$ and $MSE_O$ are the mean squared error. Is there an easy test statistic like for the correlation coefficient?